# Split dataframe into 6 dataframes based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split rows of a dataframe into 6 lists based on values in another dataframe. Working in python with the pandas package. trainX = a dataframe shaped (7352, 561) and trainY = a dataframe shaped (7351, 1)

What I want is that each row of trainX is sorted into 6 new dataframes, according to the value at the corresponding row in trainY.

If row 1 in trainY says "1", then row 1 in trainX should go to dataframe class1. If row 2 in trainY says "2", then row 2 in trainX should go to dataframe class2. And so forth until all 7351 rows in trainX are divided over classes 1 to 6.

I tried various things with for loops and iterrows() but I get stuck in syntax. How to solve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that trainY has one more row than trainX. Anyway, you could do the following:

```py
# concatenate trainX and trainY, ignore_index is False if they share the same index.
train = pd.concat([trainX, trainY], ignore_index=True, axis="columns")
# assuming that trainY.columns is ["label"]
groups = [train.loc[idxs] for idxs in train.groupby("label").groups.values()]
# I would rather create a dictionary, {1: DataFrame, 2: ....}
groups = {label: train.loc[idxs] for label, idxs in train.groupby("label").groups.items()}
```